# Export SharePoint 2007 List/View to PDF (and download this via link)

Tags: sharepoint, list, pdf, sharepoint-2007, export

I would like to be able to position a pdf-icon on top of every listview in SharePoint 2007 where users can click and download the current view (if possible with filters) as pdf. What I read here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262717/sharepoint-list-to-pdf-report) is that I need to do it programatically. This was clear.. but my question is, where I place my code and how I even know what list I need to access.

I'm completely new to SharePoint development. But I did some c#/.net/aspx stuff before. so what I could imagine is to place the functionality in the code-behind of my masterpage and then just see with javascript if a list is displayed and on-click call the same url with ?pdf=true and the do the processing, change the headers and..

But even there I got a problem - if I display many views on a page (multiple webparts) - how do I know what data to export?

Sorry, as I said.. beginner :(.. I appreciate any kind of input on this.

Cheers
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a couple of blog posts on exactly this subject.

- [Convert HTML pages to PDF format using the SharePoint User Interface](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/convert-html-pages-to-pdf-format-using.html)
- [Convert any file to PDF format using the Data View Web Part and a simple hyperlink](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/09/converting-any-file-to-pdf-using-simple.html)
- [Programmatically Converting Web / HTML pages to PDF format](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/convert-sharepoint-html-pages-to-pdf.html)
- [Converting SharePoint Lists to PDF format using a SharePoint Designer Workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/08/converting-sharepoint-lists-to-pdf.html)